# Tool to monitor bandwidth between IIS and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, iis, bandwidth

I'm looking for a way to track the data traffic between IIS (ASP.NET website) and SQL Server, both running on a local developer box (Windows 7). This is so we can improve the bandwidth usage of production websites where this traffic is going through firewalls / routers, etc.

I really thought there would be a simple perfmon stat for this that I could query but can't find anything appropriate.

Ideally I want to be able to get a simple number for the byte usage before and after some front end website tests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in the total count then the "Network Interface" performance counter set is what you're looking for.

If you want to watch it in real-time then fire up Task Manager and watch it in the Networking tab.

Comment: I don't think this will help me when both processes are running on the local machine - the network interface isn't involved so it registers no traffic.

Comment: Got ya.  I missed that they were both on the same box.  That is a tricky one. I can't think of a tool that would monitor that while on the same box.  I guess you would experiment with process monitor and see if gives any indication of the bandwidth, but I don't believe that it does.  Otherwise, if you have a NAT device like a router, you could have the traffic leave the box and come back as another IP. Or, just setup another computer for your testing.  Use a laptop if need be, depending on how much load you want to generate and how precise you need; whatever it takes to separate the two roles.

Comment: I'll proceed down the 2 server path and watch the network traffic. Thanks.